# How do I support foursquare at special events?

Tags: foursquare

I've been trying to figure out how to add locations for special events (conventions, tradeshows, etc).  So far no luck.  What's the procedure for doing so?  Some of these events I can visit beforehand if a GPS check-in is required, but many of them I'm unable to visit (as we may be sending sales people to an event a thousand miles away from where I am).

Comment: Try having a look at this page http://support.foursquare.com/entries/22578381-how-to-add-an-event

Comment: That helps, I think I'll need an "event" of some type, but how do I make it for a place other than where I'm currently located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add](https://foursquare.com/add-place) a place on foursquare using the webpage below:

https://foursquare.com/add-place

Just type "Event" for the category.